# Why I cannot replace innerHTML in this case

Tags: javascript, html

Something in the TD innerHTML content prevents it from being replaced see https://jsfiddle.net/ot8vfwc0/

How to force it to be replaced programmatically even if there is that kind of hidden weird characters ?

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col" colspan="1">TITLE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <td><br>WEIRD 
                DO NOT WANT TO BE REPLACED</td> 


        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

script:

```
    var myTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var myTbody = myTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 
    _tr = myThead.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
    _td = _tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")[0]; 
    _th.innerHTML = "TEXT REPLACED";
```

Comment: `myThead` and `_th` have not been declared anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some pretty weird 1998 JavaScript element extraction. Not to mention you're allocating so many vars you're clearly forgetting which ones you defined.

Simplify this with modern JS instead:

```
var td = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td")[0];
td.textContent="new text";
```

This gets all `<td>` elements part of a `table→tbody→tr→td` chain, we pick the first one, then we set its new content. **as text**, not as HTML, because that would be silly and a potential security risk if the content comes from anything "not hard-coded".

If we want to add DOM elements in it, we'd use `document.createElement(...)` and `td.appendChild(...)` of course:

```
// find and clear the element
var td = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td")[0];
td.textContent='';

// form new content and add it in
var p = document.createElement("p");
p = "check me out, I'm a paragraph";
td.appendChild(p);
```

Keep it simple: use modern JavaScript. It got quite a bit simpler in the last 17 years.

Comment: It's legacy application on old browser.

Comment: My code works, it's just that with this special content it does not.

Comment: Shouldn't matter - old browsers are obsolete. Even internet explorer 8 and below have literally been abandoned by Microsoft as of January 12th. And no, your code absolutely doesn't work because you're declaring so many variables that you don't even notice that you've **not** declared `_th`, which you're trying to use. Your code is quite broken, and you need to clean it up. Thankfully, http://caniuse.com can help you figure out which modern syntax is safe for your target audience.

Comment: Yes it matters since all the users are corporate users they are stuck with IE8 at the moment

Comment: Not since January 12th. Any real corporate users can no longer actually use IE8 or below, because Microsoft has, goddamn *finally*, shut off support of any and all kind, even corporate payed kind. People who still use IE8 or below are never going to get security updates ever again, and any bugs and exploits still open, will stay open. Unless you're talking about companies with illegal copies of windows installed. Then whatever, they're kind of already on their own.

Comment: And look: http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector says it works on IE8 just fine as long as we use normal CSS2 selectors. Which is what we're doing here. Nice: start using it.

Comment: Migration in big Fortune 500 does not occur in one night. Of course they will migrate but only when Corporate will do so in a few months.

Comment: migration of companies that pay Microsoft for extended support started years ago, and finished before January 12, because that was Microsoft's official hard deadline. But none of that matters because `document.querySelector` **works** for IE8, so this argument is irrelevant. Use all the modern JS you can, with the help of http://caniuse.com and maybe quirksmode, and get better, easier to maintain code out of it.

Comment: I can tell you that's not the case at least in our department I'd wish they had I agree that's crazy :)

Comment: Indeed, but again: document.querySelector works, so rewrite this code to a shorter, cleaner, better form while you can, because you owe it to your future self.

Comment: OK I'll use querySelector :)

Comment: your answer checkmark says otherwise. Remember that stackoverflow is not just for your benefit, but everyone who finds your question after you've solved it and moved on. Selecting a quick answer rather than a *good* answer doesn't help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var myTbody = myTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 
_tr = myTbody.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
_td = _tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
_td.innerHTML = "TEXT REPLACED";
```

Replace `myThead` with `myTbody` and `_th` with `_td`.

Comment: seriously, let's not keep using 1998 JavaScript, use modern JS (we've had `document.querySelector` for quite a while now)

Comment: Totally agreed, it is a much better and clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

`myThead` and `_th` are undefined. Replace them with `myTbody` and `_td` and it will work.